# pg_search with modified content

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, pg, pg-search

Does anyone know how to modify columns content before pg_search stores it?

Full explanation:

I have model `Article` with columns `title` and `body`. In `body` I store article's body html.

PgSearch is configured with `multisearchable against: [:title, :body]`.

When I search I get search content with html tags included, but I would like to stip all html tags from text before new `PgSearch::Document` is created in the first place.

Comment: If you find you can't do this at the Rails level, you could create a trigger that maintains a stripped version of the column in the database and then `pg_search` that instead of the "real" column. It'll waste storage though, so it's not ideal.

Comment: Thank you for you anwser! That currently seems the only possible way to go. Although it would truly be nice if there was some kind of before filter :).